# How to generate script with 'Termination Character'

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

[image][image]i want bulk copy of sql data to other DB. but problem is here that when i am trying to execute this insert statement.

it gives me error like

```
    Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
    Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''.
    Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
    Incorrect syntax near ''.
```

I found the solution that `N' '` creating problem. But when i replacing this it is just coping `N'`. So how can replace the whole query. There are too many row so i cannot do manually to to `N''`.

When trying to copy it just copy this part

```
    INSERT [dbo].[HaveWantMaster]
       ([HaveWantMasterID],
        [Type],
        [Description],
        [TotalAvailable],
        [Status],
        [Deleted],
        [CreatedBy],
        [CreatedOn],
        [UpdatedBy],
        [UpdatedOn])
VALUES (409,
        0,
        N'tap',
        3,
        N'
```

Comment: @JoePhillips pardon i didnt get you.

Comment: I don't see any problems with the SQL you're executing. Works fine for me

Comment: But i showed you error as well.

Comment: N' ' is not an issue, it is there to tell: this is a unicode varchar / char

Comment: Please create a test case that we can reproduce, including the table creation. I can't reproduce this

Comment: It appears you've edited your answer to say that you are having trouble copying and pasting. I no longer understand what you are having an issue with... your second example is simply invalid SQL

Comment: @JoePhillips plz see image

Comment: @SAL I see it. What parts I can see look valid in the image. Can you simplify the code to create a useful test case where the issue still happens? Start by commenting out lines until you're down to a simple example that reproduces the issue

Comment: Still can't reproduce. Good luck

Comment: Post a complete example that we can run that reproduces this issue. Or post it up to a site like http://rextester.com/l/sql_server_online_compiler - without an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) this question should be closed.

Comment: Already given all thing regarding to question still incomplete. What need more?

Comment: There is probably either something other than a regular space between those two quotes, or a space and something non-printable. So rather than guess, wrap the `N' '` with this: `SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(20), N' ', 1);` and update the question with the results.

Comment: @srutzky `Error converting data type nvarchar to varbinary.`

Comment: @SAL Oops, sorry, that style number was supposed to be a 0 (or not there): `SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(20), N' ', 0);`. Please try again. Sorry :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example is the following:
`PRINT 'THIS IS AMAZING`

> Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Unclosed quotation mark after the
>   character string 'THIS IS AMAZING '.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line
>   1 Incorrect syntax near 'THIS IS AMAZING '.

Instead, properly close your characters: `PRINT 'THIS IS AMAZING'`

The delimiter (`'`), or `CHAR(39)` of the ASCII characters  is a special character in SQL Server that denotes a string. When the parser reads this character, it assumes the proceeding characters until the next delimiter of type (') are part of the same string.

```
PRINT ASCII(CHAR(39) + ' ' + CHAR(39))
PRINT ASCII(' ')
```

> [Delimiter]: 39 [Space]: 32

The parser reads the first statement as the same as CHAR(39) + '' + CHAR(39) (*since '' and '' represent a single quotation per set*), so the optimizer is smart enough to recognize repeating delimiters and return the special character.

However, in your code you failed to provide us with the actual code, so we cannot verify if your code has special characters that your environment does not show. You can copy paste the "space" from the original text/sql file and check for special characters like `CL`/`RF` characters.

```
SELECT ASCII('
')
```

> 13

Note CHAR(13) is often mistaken for CHAR(10), the former begin equivalent to the enter key on your keyboard, even though in the query they effectively look the same in this example:

```
PRINT 'HOW ABOUT THIS' + CHAR(10) + 'BROWN COW' + CHAR(13) + 'HOLY MOLY'
--returns
HOW ABOUT THIS
BROWN COW
HOLY MOLY
```

**CONCLUSION**:

- Investigate the actual position of the error. The message tells you a delimiter is not enclosed, not where it failed.
- If it is from dynamic SQL, understand it is possible to enclose an incorrectly structured query in a string.

For example

```
EXEC(' PRINT''MyPeople')
```

will pass the parser, but this is actually reads

```
PRINT'MyPeople
```

- Check for special characters that may be failing your parser and consider again what is running this batch. The **ENVIRONMENT IS VERY IMPORTANT**.
- `N'` fails syntax. The (`N`) simply tells the parser it is dealing with `NVARCHAR` characters. You must enclose all delimiters in SQL Server.

Comment: corrected ironically my own mistake about confusing CHAR(10) and CHAR(13)

Comment: @clifton-h nice elaboration. i am trying to reproduce. I don't think so it was **regular space**. It was working on regular space.

Comment: @SAL Yeah. Now you `know` its a regular space and the syntax of that specific position is not wrong, you have made progress! Try checking the parsing to each individual statement, if you have not already cleared the environment as the culprit...which, can definitely be a probability. Syntax errors can be tricky, especially if the code is executed from outside SQL Server through an application

Comment: @SAL plus now you know how to look for trouble characters, which bulk importing from, say a file, can bring into your environment. Never miss an opportunity to learn, I say. :)

Comment: Yes i am checking. Will update you regarding. Yeah i want to learn heartedly.

Answer (score 0):

Come to the point now.`Ascii 0 (zero) written to char(1) field`.
 It is begin getting error due to `null-terminated (ASCII 0)`. As per the http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=47571

The issue is, strings in SQL Server are not null-terminated (ASCII 0) as are strings in C++ -- so when you write a single-character string from C++ into SQL Server, you're getting only the first character (there are really two; the character and a terminator) -- the terminator is actually being truncated. When you try to write a "blank" string (which really contains just the terminator), no trucation occurs. So you're getting the terminator itself.

Comment: if this solves your error, please mark it as an answer!

Comment: Actually this is not solving my error. but just knew the exact problem. I could do by replace data but i want to know what is the bottleneck.